# Python openpyxl multiple conditional formatting entries execution order problem

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to use openpyxl on a sheet of data to highlight values that are beyond a specific value while simultaneously using ColorScale to give me a quick visual of how an array of values appears. I'm doing this with Conditional Formatting but the execution order is important. I want to run the highlight first and if it matches stop (using `stopIfTrue`). However, I'm finding that openpyxl doesn't seem to follow python execution order to establish the conditional formatting order.

For example:

```
import random
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import ColorScaleRule, CellIsRule
from openpyxl.styles import Font, PatternFill

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb.active
sheet.title = 'FUBAR'

# write data into cells
for row_num in range(1, 30):
    sheet.cell(row=row_num, column=1, value=round(random.random(), 2))
    sheet.cell(row=row_num, column=3, value=round(random.random(),2))

# define two rules
highlight_rule = CellIsRule(operator='greaterThan', formula=[0.75], stopIfTrue=True, font=Font(color='FFFFFF', bold=True), fill=PatternFill(start_color='FF0000', end_color='FF0000', fill_type='solid'))
scale_rule = ColorScaleRule(start_type='num', start_value=0.10, start_color='63BE7B', mid_type='num', mid_value=0.50, mid_color='FFEB84', end_type='num', end_value=0.75, end_color='F8696B')

# apply rules to C column data, highlight second
sheet.conditional_formatting.add('C1:C29', scale_rule)
sheet.conditional_formatting.add('C1:C29', highlight_rule)
# apply rules to A column data, highlight first
sheet.conditional_formatting.add('A1:A29', highlight_rule)
sheet.conditional_formatting.add('A1:A29', scale_rule)

# Save the result
wb.save('output.xlsx')
```

After running this short script, I'd expect that the `A` column would have the `highlight_rule` listed first and should have some random highlights with bright red (`FF0000`) and column `C` to be all ColorScaled (no bright red highlights). However, after execution the highlight_rule is always listed second in the `Conditional Formatting`-->`Manage Rules...` for both columns of data!

Manually correcting the issue from within Excel, I can see that Excel will actually take a comma-separated cell list for applying Conditional Formatting like `=$A$1:$A$29,$C$1:$C$29` but openpyxl doesn't like this input so I have to create multiple instances of `sheet.conditional_formatting.add()`.

Is there a way to make the result of this execution consistent?

Comment: Why should the order of entry matter? Conditional Formatting explicitly supports priorities.

Comment: @Charlie Clark, how might one go about that? It seems questions in this regard are sparse.